# how can we change a compatibilty mode of exe file from java code and run it

Tags: java

I am trying to execute .exe file from java by connecting to command prompt but, when i run the file i am getting a warning that windows has stopped the execution. Then after a long search i have changed the compatibility of file manually from windows xp to win 7 but i cannot do this manually every time because i am trying to automate entire procedure from the java code.

Help me out, if there is any way to change the compatibility mode from command prompt so that i can run that from java code

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Windows "reg" command to add/delete/read registry elements.
in the registry path `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers` You will find all executables(.exe) compatibility options that have been changed, you can also add your own application and changed its options

> This is a list of the available options you can change

Privilege Level:

- `RUNASADMIN` - Runs the program with the administrative security token

Display Settings:

- `DISABLETHEMES` - Disable Visual Themes
- `640X480` - Run in 640 x 480 screen resolution
- `HIGHDPIAWARE` - Disable display scaling on high DPI settings
- `256COLOR` - Run in 256 colors
- `DISABLEDWM` - Disable Desktop Composition

Compatibility Mode:

- `WIN95` - Windows 95
- `WIN98` - Windows 98
- `WIN4SP5` - Windows NT 4.0 SP5
- `WIN2000` - Windows 2000
- `WINXPSP2` - Windows XP SP2
- `WINXPSP3` - Windows XP SP3
- `VISTARTM` - Vista
- `VISTASP1` - Vista SP1
- `VISTASP2` - Vista SP2
- `WIN7RTM` - Windows 7
- `WINSRV03SP1` - Windows Server 2003 SP1
- `WINSRV08SP1` - Windows Server 2008 SP1

<sup>[Source](http://www.verboon.info/2011/03/running-an-application-as-administrator-or-in-compatibility-mode/)</sup>

> Here is an example how to run "reg add" command using Runtime method

```
String exePath = "C:\\Program Files\\MyApp\\Test5.exe";
String exe_run_option = "WINXPSP3";// run with Windows XP SP3 compatibilities
String command = "reg.exe Add \"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\AppCompatFlags\\Layers\" /v \"" + exePath + "\" /d \"" + exe_run_option + "\"";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
//if the value already exists this will cause the reg command to pause and eat the cpu performance, so we give it a timeout
p.waitFor(2,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//You can check the exit value of the process generally a 0 value means a succeed operation
try{
    if(p.exitValue() != 0){
        // we probably have an error
    }
}catch(IllegalThreadStateException e){
    //the process didn't finish execution and we tried to see it's exit value(terminated in 2 seconds forcibly)
    //here you can try removing the key and adding it again with a different value using "reg delete" command (you might need to read the current value to add it together with the new one)
}
```

#### Please keep in mind

> 1. That if you need to add multiple values for one executable don't call the same command more than once for that application this will cause the reg editor to stun as pointed above, instead just add the value at the same time like this
>      `String exe_run_option = "option1 option2 option3";//..etc`
> 2. That this will only work with executable files (.exe), as an example you can't do this for a jar file instead you might use a .exe runner(wrapper) file and apply these options to it and then it runs the jar file.
> 3. That You must have administrator privileges to add elements to the registry thus the java application must have admin rights during the execution of the code above

Answer (score 0):

This is also addressed here:

[How can I set the compatibility mode for an executable from the command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/379375/how-can-i-set-the-compatibility-mode-for-an-executable-from-the-command-line)

Not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is for execute the command from java code.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your command");
p.waitFor();
```

Comment: i want the command with which we can change the compatibilty of .exe file from windowsXP to Windows 7